# Python quit unexpectedly

Tags: vimscript-python, macos, crash

When I start vim (homebrew installation, `/usr/local/bin/vim`), I get the error "Python quit unexpectedly."

How do I make python work with my vim?

```
$ which vim
/usr/local/bin/vim

$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python

$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3

$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled May 17 2017 10:08:18)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-599
Compiled by Homebrew
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_old_static
+arabic          +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  -tag_any_white
+autocmd         +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tcl
-balloon_eval    +folding         +mouse_xterm     +termguicolors
-browse          -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
++builtin_terms  +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+byte_offset     -gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
+channel         -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +timers
+cindent         +iconv           +num64           +title
-clientserver    +insert_expand   +packages        -toolbar
+clipboard       +job             +path_extra      +user_commands
+cmdline_compl   +jumplist        +perl            +vertsplit
+cmdline_hist    +keymap          +persistent_undo +virtualedit
+cmdline_info    +lambda          +postscript      +visual
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visualextra
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +viminfo
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python          +vreplace
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +wildignore
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildmenu
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +windows
+dialog_con      -lua             +rightleft       +writebackup
+diff            +menu            +ruby            -X11
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -xfontset
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xim
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xpm
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      +startuptime     -xsmp
+eval            +mouse_dec       +statusline      -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        -mouse_gpm       -sun_workshop    -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   +syntax          
+farsi           +mouse_netterm   +tag_binary      
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
Compilation: clang -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DMACOS_X_UNIX  -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1       
Linking: clang   -L. -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/local/lib -o vim        -lm  -lncurses -liconv -framework Cocoa   -fstack-protector  -L/System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE -lperl -F/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks -framework Python   -lruby.2.0.0 -lobjc
```

Comment: Cross-posted: http://stackoverflow.com/q/44022249/660921

Comment: @Carpetsmoker yeah? Allowed right?

Comment: Not strictly disallowed, but not encouraged either. Usually it's fine to cross-post if you don't get an answer within a reasonable amount of time, although a day is pretty short. Personally I'd wait at least a week. The thing is that people might answer one question, and that then someone else will duplicate this effort answering the question on another site, so *if* you do cross-post, then always mention where the question has been posted before, so people can check if it already has an answer there (hence my comment with the link on both questions).

Comment: At any rate, do you use plugins? What does your vimrc look like? Does it work when you don't use any plugins/vimrc? Did you try some of the steps here: https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/585 (first result from internet search)?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker is there a way to run w/o launching plugins and vimrc? Do I have to just change the filename one time?

Comment: You can use `vim -u NONE -U NONE -N`. Also see: [How do I debug my vimrc file?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/51)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker actually, I just ran `brew unlink python`, and python no longer crashes. However, my plugins like YCM don't work.

Answer (score 1):

Running `brew unlink python` fixed the problem for me, now vim runs with python fine.

However, it has caused my plugins like YCM to start crashing.